# Status check before sending email

Tags: email, task, netsuite, suitescript

I have the below script, I want to send the email when the task is completed, I have inputted the check task lines exactly as the oracle documentation specifies and the script works fine without these lines, but when I put them in I get the error 'Syntax error: missing ; before statement'

These are the lines causing the problem:

```
let taskStatus = task.checkStatus(searchTask1);
if (taskStatus.status === 'COMPLETE')
```

I cannot see where there is anything missing here, can anyone help? Thank you

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ScheduledScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/

define(['N/task','N/email'],

/**
* @param {record} record
* @param {search} search
*/

function(task, email) {

var FILE_ID = 433961; 
var SEARCH_ID = 1610;

function execute(scriptContext) {

var searchTask1 = task.create({
taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH

});

searchTask1.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
searchTask1.fileId = FILE_ID;

var searchTaskId1 = searchTask1.submit();

let taskStatus = task.checkStatus(searchTask1);
if (taskStatus.status === 'COMPLETE'){
email.send({
            author: 3499,
            recipients: 'An email address',
            subject: 'A subject',
            body: 'body text',
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you try to use `var` instead of `let` (`var taskStatus`)? However, you're if statement will always evaluate to false as the task has just been submitted within your script.

Comment: Thank you W.S. That did work and the error went. However you are correct, this doesn't appear to work, no email comes through. Is there another sort of conditional paramter I can use which essentially says, send the email once the CSV export has finished? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to execute your scheduled script again. When you execute the scheduled script, save the taskId somewhere (file cabinet, for example) and then once the task is complete, delete it. You probably also want to put a counter in somewhere so that the scheduled script doesn't keep running, should something go wrong. Something like this;

```
function(task, email) {

    var FILE_ID = 433961;
    var SEARCH_ID = 1610;

    function execute(scriptContext) {
        var shouldExecuteThis = false;
        var searchTask1 = task.create({
            taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
        });

        searchTask1.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
        searchTask1.fileId = FILE_ID;

        var searchTaskId1 = searchTask1.submit();
        // TODO: Save the searchTaskId1 somewhere so we can check the status later. (File cabinet to a text file.)
        if (searchTaskId1) {
            var searchTaskStatus = task.checkStatus({taskId: searchTaskId1});
            // Still pending, so we need to check again later.
            if (searchTaskStatus.status === task.TaskStatus.PENDING || searchTaskStatus.status === task.TaskStatus.PROCESSING) {
                shouldExecuteThis = true;
            }
            // The task has completed, update the configuration file and log the results.
            if (searchTaskStatus.status === task.TaskStatus.COMPLETE) {
                // Delete the searchTaskId1 from where is it saved.
                // SEND EMAIL
                email.send({
                    author: 3499,
                    recipients: 'An email address',
                    subject: 'A subject',
                    body: 'body text',
                });
            }
            if (shouldExecuteThis) {
                var thisTaskId = '';
                var thisTask = task.create({
                    taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT,
                    scriptId: runtime.getCurrentScript().id,
                    deploymentId: runtime.getCurrentScript().deploymentId
                });

                try {
                    thisTaskId = thisTask.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                    log.error('TASK FAILED', e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```